# Google Social Authentication troubles

Tags: google-chrome, oauth-2.0, python-3.7, django-2.1

Hi I am new to social login's. When I click the google button I can get redirected to a working social view. As I attempt to log in I get the following trackback.

I have been having a very difficult time understanding how this all works can someone please give me a hand? I tried multiple tutorials on google social authentication.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_django\utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_django\views.py", line 33, in complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\actions.py", line 43, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 40, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 259, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\oauth.py", line 405, in auth_complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py", line 259, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\oauth.py", line 416, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_django\strategy.py", line 107, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 80, in authenticate
    return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 83, in pipeline
    out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\base.py", line 113, in run_pipeline
    result = func(*args, **out) or {}
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\pipeline\user.py", line 75, in create_user
    'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_core\strategy.py", line 53, in create_user
    return self.storage.user.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bmxfi\Anaconda3\envs\QuestionWorldEnv\lib\site-packages\social_django\storage.py", line 79, in create_user
    user = cls.user_model().objects.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create_user() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'date_of_birth'
[22/Jan/2019 00:30:51] "GET /auth/complete/google-oauth2/?state=9RDDB6MAo3C5i0MDKQuHBX9QOiyEQBcB&code=4/2gDFXySOhdxEVkI4gMXQ9vNUhpuEvqm1rYoCxgM85d6LrNu2HqhnjRNcUs9ZzRql4KMbdWVpXO0NACsS111yhSY&scope=email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email HTTP/1.1" 500 184864



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'World1',
    'social_django',
]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',  # <--
]


SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
# Google+ SignIn (google-plus)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

All that was needed here was the setting

`SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL='/auth/complete/google-oauth2/'`

I had this setting as `LOGIN_URL` instead of `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL`.

and then change my `LOGIN_URL` to the template after the user gets authenticated not the actual login template itself.